# How can i use laravel relationship reference in datatables jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatable, datatables

For example, I have a **Laravel Relationship**, `appointments` table has a reference to `doctor` in the `doctor_id` attribute and I want to fetch the doctor's name like `$appointment->doctor->name`, the problem is how can I fetch that using ajax call in my datatable. This is my code.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#myTable').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
      url: "{{ route('appointments.index') }}",
      dataSrc: 'appointments'
    },
    "columns": [{
      "data": "doctor_id"
    }, {
      "data": "patient_id"
    } {
      "data": function(data) {
        return '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs btn-edit" data-id="' + data.id + '">Edit</button>';
      }
    }]
  });
});
```

I want the doctor and patient names where their are ids.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking, however I can tell you that you have a syntax error - a missing `,` in your `columns` array

Comment: Have any relation between them?? Please share your view

Comment: What I can suggest you is make the route return data in the form of `ajax`. Then use JSON properties to get the corresponding value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using Belongs to relation and Eager loading (use `with` method).
For example:

#### Post Belongs to User. so defind relation on model Post.php

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

#### PostControler.php

```
 public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $posts = Post::with(['user'])->paginate(15);
        return ['posts' => $posts];
    }
```

#### Result:

```
{
    "posts": {
        "current_page": 1,
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "user_id": 1,
                "title": "Bai viet so 1",
                "content": " \ndasdadaddad",
                "created_at": "2020-05-07T07:29:14.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2020-05-07T09:38:12.000000Z",
                "user": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "HoangQuan",
                    "email": "admin1@example.com",
                    "email_verified_at": null,
                    "created_at": "2020-05-07T07:28:15.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2020-05-07T07:28:15.000000Z"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "user_id": 1,
                "title": "Bai viet so 2",
                "content": " \n​",
                "created_at": "2020-05-07T07:29:42.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2020-05-07T07:29:42.000000Z",
                "user": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "HoangQuan",
                    "email": "admin1@example.com",
                    "email_verified_at": null,
                    "created_at": "2020-05-07T07:28:15.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2020-05-07T07:28:15.000000Z"
                }
            },
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Appointment Model use this

```
public function doctor(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Appointment');

}
```